# Регулярное выражение в ячейке массива

Tags: c++

Можно ли в ячейку массива символов поместить регулярное выражение?
Например чтобы при обращении к этой ячейке символ удовлетворяющий регулярному выражению как то определялся. То есть по сути в ячейке мне нужно множество символов. Можно ли это реализовать и если да то подскажите пожалуйста как.

Comment: Если под ячейкой массива символов понимается элемент массива char, то и хранить в нем очень желательно только char.  Само регулярное выражение может быть представлено разными формами (например строкой или объектом).

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в ячейке хранилось например любой символ из диапазона a-z как мне это сделать не можете подсказать?